# Apache directory wrong secret password

Tags: authentication, ldap, apacheds

I've just install a fresh apache directory on debian stretch. When trying to login via Apache directory studio using DN : **uid=admin,ou=system** ans password **secret** as stated in the documentation , connection fails whilst the network connection was OK at the previous step

network connection
[image]

login
[image]

Comment: The `dn` seems incomplete, domain components are missing `dn : [...],dc=example,dc=com`

Answer (score 0):

I was using the *10636* instead of the **10389** network port